# Cucumber feature file not getting executed from Test runner

Tags: junit, automation, frameworks, cucumber, bdd

I am trying to run my Cucumber feature file from Test runner but when executed it does nothing on the console. It does not throw any exception or error also. please advise as what may be wrong here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLcjL.png)

please find the code below

```
package TestRunners;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features= {"src/test/java/AppFeatures"  
        },
        glue= {"StepDefinations"}
        )

public class AmazonTest {

}
```

Comment: Also try the [10 minute tutorial](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/) from Cucumber. It will use JUnit 5 instead of JUnit 4.

Answer (score 0):

Just had same error, when I was trying to run with "Run as -> Cucumber Feature" command nothing was happening.

It seems like the run configuration was not created at all, so what I did is go to "Run as -> Run Configurations" and I created the run configuration manually (go to "Cucumber feature" option and click the "Launch New Configuration" button).